# How do I escape commas with Jmeter reading from a CSV data set?

Tags: java, csv, jmeter

I am testing a chat bot with inputs, and one of the rows reads, for example

```
entityInput, Just in case, where is the nearest doctor's office
```

The input is sending only "Just in case". I have tried `Just in case\, where is the nearest doctor's office`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you read the [CSV specification (RFC 4180)](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt) or the [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)? It says exactly that you don't escape `,` but rather wrap whole text into `""` so

```
entityInput, "Just in case, where is the nearest doctor's office"
```

should work as long as implementation is compliant.

Comment: Good Answer. I’d add this tip: Use a library for reading/writing such data, like [*Apache Commons CSV*](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/).

Comment: Thanks, I knew I'd done this before. Note you also have to set "Allow Quoted Data" to True on the CSV Data Set Config node.

Answer (score 2):

In JMeter there is an extra change needed.

You should have a CSV Data Set Set Config in you test plan. In which case you should look for a setting called "Allow quoted data?" and change it to true.

Then

```
entityInput, "Just in case, where is the nearest doctor's office"
```

will work.

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/40273206